# Lazy-loading association does not properly initialize child association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false) // I've tried @OneToOne also, same result
    @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
    private Bar bar;

    // this is a business key, though not mapped as unique for legacy reasons
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long fooNo; 

    // getters/setters + other properties
}

@Entity
public class Bar {
    @OneToOne(optional = true, mappedBy = "bar", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Foo foo;

    // getters/setters + other properties
}
```

**NOTE:** This is the correct mapping: @ManyToOne and @OneToOne (it wasn't designed by me). I have tried @OneToOne on both sides also, with the same result.

Basically, I can have a Bar without a Foo object, but everytime I have a Foo, there has to be a Bar associated with it. Foo is considered the parent object (which is why its the owner of the association), but Bar can stand alone in certain cases.

I then load a `Foo` object like this:

```
SELECT f FROM Foo f WHERE f.fooNo = :fooNo
```

`foo.getBar()` correctly fetches the appropriate `Bar`, as expected. However, `foo.getBar().getFoo()` is `null`. It seems the other side of this relationship is not correctly initialized by JPA/hibernate. Any ideas why this is happening and how I can fix it?

I use Hibernate 3.2.1 as my JPA implementation, which we are using through EJB3 beans (though that is probably irrelevant).

Comment: Did you try `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`?

Comment: You mean to put that on the `Foo` reference? I thought that was the default, when not specified?

Comment: Could you explain how this objects must be related, because current mapping is confusing.

Comment: Another idea: have you tried putting the annotation on the getter/setters, not on the field?

Comment: @AleksandrM I added a brief comment on the idea behind the mapping. @durron597 I have not, but I can see internally that the field has the value null when I inspect the object in debug mode. I don't think putting mappings on getter/setters will change this? `Bar.foo`shouldn't be lazy loaded (as `bar` was lazy loaded through `Foo`.

Comment: @MortenJacobsen: Can you humor me and try it?

Comment: Are you setting both sides of this bidirectional relationship?  Setting only the foo->bar side will result in the database being updated, but leave bar->foo unchanged until bar is refreshed from the database.

Comment: @Chris I'm not creating new instances, I'm loading existing instances from the database.

Comment: I'd still check you always correctly populate bar, as it is quite common to only set one side and expect the other to be populated by the provider.  Try em.refresh on bar.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your assotiation?   ManyToOne usually implies oneToMany on other.

Comment: This should probably have been a comment instead of an answer. Yes, this is the current mapping (its not designed by me). I have tried @OneToOne on both sides (because that is logically what it is), but it does not change anything.